# Understanding structures in C

Tags: c

I've tried to create a program that allows the user to create a table with the number of rows and columns which he declares and then to insert the values that he wants into the table. But there is something wrong in the code and so when the user insert the numbers the program prints only the last one. What did i do wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
     int rows;
     int columns;
     int dimension;
     int values[];
} table;

int i = 0;

int main() {
table tab_1;
tab_1.dimension = (int) malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Loop that allows the user to insert the number of rows and columns

```
do
{
    printf("Insert the numbers of rows\n");
    scanf("%d", &tab_1.rows);
} while (tab_1.rows < 0);

do
{
    printf("Insert the number of columns\n");
    scanf("%d", &tab_1.columns);
} while (tab_1.columns < 0);

tab_1.dimension = tab_1.rows * tab_1.columns;
```

Loop to insert the values (in my opinion here is the issue )

```
while (i < tab_1.dimension) {
    printf("Insert values\n");
    scanf("%d", tab_1.values);
    i++;
    
}

i = 0;
```

Loop that prints the values

```
while (i < tab_1.dimension) 
{
    printf("\t%d ", *tab_1.values);
    i++;
}
return 0;
}
```

Here it is an example of what the user insert and the answer that the program gives to him:

Input:

```
Insert the numbers of rows:
2
Insert the numbers of columns:
2
Insert the values:
1
Insert the values:
2
Insert the values:
3
Insert the values:
4
```

Output:

```
4 4 4 4
```

Comment: Please properly indent your code. It makes easier to understand, for you and for us.

Comment: Please take some time to think more about e.g. `tab_1.dimension = (int) malloc(sizeof(int));` It is *very* wrong.

Comment: And with `values` you have a [*flexible array member*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member). Unfortunately it means you can't create instances of the structure without using `malloc` for *the whole structure*.

Comment: In `scanf("%d", tab_1.values);` you must add the element index to be scanned into, e.g. `scanf("%d", &tab_1.values[i]);`

Comment: I appreciate that you attempted to translate your original code to English. (I presume, since the structure is defined with `rows`, `columns`, and `values`, but some of your code uses `larghezza` and `valori`.) However, the translation is incomplete since some of the code is still in Italian. You should prepare a [mre] that actually compiles and runs—do not just make some changes manually and assume that is good enough. Provide code that actually compiles. Two solutions to your issue are a flexible array member or a pointer member, and an [mre] would help us see which you were aiming for.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So maybe it's better if i "convert" the `values[]` array into a pointer `*values` but i don't know how can add the values to the pointer

Comment: @EricPostpischil I've tried to add a minimal reproducible example to my question, i hope that it's more readable now

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude about the `malloc` statement, i'm still studying it and apparently i've not understand it well, could you please tell me what the right syntax would be in this case?

Answer (score 0):

In your struct you declare `int values[];` but this is an array of *zero* elements. This is used to declare a variable sized array at the end of the struct but that only works when you dynamically allocate the array with `malloc`. For example:

```
table *pTab_1 = malloc(sizeof(table) + 10*sizeof(int));
```

This allocates the struct, plus room for 10 integers.

(and look at the comments for all the other problems in your code)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was wondering if would make more sense to replace the `values []` field with a `* values` and then use the line of code you wrote

Comment: No. Then it will be a pointer to a separate block of memory.